# Is Async.Start guaranteed to finish?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

I couldn't find any documentation for this.

I want to ask whether using `Async.Start` in F# is guaranteed to finish, even if the caller or the main thread exits before it finishes.
Specifically, I want to log a lot of data to the disk after processing each input and want to know whether I can simply using Async.Start for this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If the main thread exits then your process ends. Why would it still run your computation?

Comment: You actually ask more than 1 question in one question:  "Is Async.Start guaranteed to finish?" and ask about difference behavior in multiple OS. Please update your question to focus on one problem to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET there are [two kinds of threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads). Foreground threads keep the process alive. `Async.Start` runs the computation on the thread pool. Thread pool threads are background threads. So running async operations typically won't finish.

The following program prints `Starting`, `Exiting main` / `async true` and `T2 done`:

```
open System.Threading

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    printfn "Starting"

    let t1 = new Thread(fun () ->
        Thread.Sleep 10000
        printfn "T1 done")
    t1.IsBackground <- true
    t1.Start()

    let t2 = new Thread(fun () ->
        Thread.Sleep 1000
        printfn "T2 done")
    t2.IsBackground <- false
    t2.Start()

    Async.Start (async {
        printfn "async %b" Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground
        do! Async.Sleep 10000
        printfn "Async done"
    })

    printfn "Exiting main"
    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful. Unfortunately, the question is closed.